# realloc(): invalid next size error in C program

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that reads an array of employee records from an input file and sorts them separately using insertion sort and quick sort. It also finds out the time taken by the two sorts for different array sizes. I'm supposed to find the estimated cutoff size above which quick sort becomes faster than insertion sort. For doing that I have written the function estimateCutoff() which in turn calls testRun()...(testRun() finds the time taken for sorting a particular array while estimateCutoff() compares the two times). However I'm getting a particular error each time the program runs which is :

```
realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Upon debugging the code I have found out that the error occurs during allocation of array emp2 in testRun() that has been in return called by estimateCutoff().

> realloc(): invalid next size
>   Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
>   __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
>   51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.

Can anybody please tell me where I'm going wrong.

```
int estimateCutoff(empl * emp,int size){
    int min=0,max=size,mid;
    mid=(min+max)/2;
    time t=testRun(emp,mid);

    do
    {
        if(t.IStime<t.QStime)
            min=mid;
        else if(t.IStime>t.QStime)
            max=mid;
        else if(t.IStime==t.QStime)
            return mid;
        mid=(min+max)/2;
        t=testRun(emp,mid);
    } while(mid!=min && mid!= max);

    return mid;
}
```

This is the `testRun()` function:

```
time testRun(empl * emp,int size){
    int i;
    empl *emp1=malloc(sizeof(empl)*size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        emp1[i]=emp[i];
    }

    time t;
    struct timeval t1,t2,t3,t4;
    double elapsedTime1,elapsedTime2;

    gettimeofday(&t1,NULL);
    iter_insertionsort(emp1,size);
    gettimeofday(&t2,NULL);
    elapsedTime1=(t2.tv_sec-t1.tv_sec)*1000.0;
    elapsedTime1+=(t2.tv_usec-t1.tv_usec)/1000.0;
    t.IStime=elapsedTime1;

    empl *emp2=malloc(sizeof(empl)*size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        emp2[i]=emp[i];
    }

    gettimeofday(&t3,NULL);
    itr_quicksort(emp2,size,1);
    gettimeofday(&t4,NULL);
    elapsedTime2=(t4.tv_sec-t3.tv_sec)*1000.0;
    elapsedTime2+=(t4.tv_usec-t3.tv_usec)/1000.0;
    t.QStime=elapsedTime2;

    return t;
}
```

The `main()` function is given below:

```
#include<stack.h>
#include<quick.h>
int main(){

    int arraycapacity=10;
    empl * emp=malloc(sizeof(empl)*arraycapacity);
    FILE * ptr=fopen("1000","r");
    int size=0;
    while(!feof(ptr))
    {
        fscanf(ptr,"%[^ ] %d\n",emp[size].name,&(emp[size].empID));
        size++;
        if(size==arraycapacity)
        {
            arraycapacity=arraycapacity*2;
            emp=realloc(emp,sizeof(empl)*arraycapacity);
        }
    }
    int mid=estimateCutoff(emp,size);
    printf("mid = %d\n",mid);
    fclose(ptr);
}
```

Comment: The message means you've gone trampling outside the bounds of a piece of allocated memory and have corrupted the control information that the memory management code uses.  If possible, get [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and use it to diagnose the problem.  Failing that, work out where you're trampling out of bounds.

Comment: Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: I'll use Valgrind then and see if that works.

Comment: and thanks for the info BTW !!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler valgrind gives the following errror: VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
--10016-- si_code=1;  Faulting address: 0x790523C492;  sp: 0x1002ca9e30

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal

Answer (score 3):

In `main` you are doubling the array size for every test but never check if `realloc` was successful.

You are calling `malloc` twice in every call to `testRun` which is happening from inside a loop in `estimateCutoff`, but you never `free` any memory and you never check if `malloc` was successful.

This is all a recipe for disaster. You should take the following steps:

- Check that all memory allocation and reallocation succeeds.
- `free()` the memory allocations at the end of each test in `testrun`.
- Set a limit on `arraycapacity`
- Change the control loop in `main` which wrongly uses `feof()` to

```
while(fscanf(ptr, "%[^ ] %d\n", emp[size].name, &(emp[size].empID)) == 2)
{
    // ...
}
```

because the `scanf` family returns the number of items successfully scanned.

Comment: I did as you said, however, after a few iterations ,program still gives error :         Continuing.
corrupted size vs. prev_size

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51 ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.

Comment: Perhpas there is a fault in the sorting functions.

Comment: The sorting function are working just fine and so is testRun() independently. It's only when I use estimateCutoff() that the error happens.

Comment: Suppose `else if(t.IStime==t.QStime)` is never true? They are floating point values. Anyway you have already tested `<` and `>` so why the `else` and a needless test?